# Check if one date is between two dates or not

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following three dates

```
Date1 = 2022-02-07 20:06:14.379392
Date2 = 2021-02-07 20:06:14.379393
Date3 = 2022-02-06 00:00:00.000
```

and I want to check, if `Date3` is between `Date1` and `Date2`.

As of right now the `Date3` is between `Date1` and `Date2`, but how can I check this?

Currently I am trying something like this

```
if (Date1.isBefore(Date3) &&
    Date2.isAfter(Date3)) {
  print("date3 is between date1 and date2");
} else {
  print("date3 isn't between date1 and date2");
}
```

But it's always showing, that the `Date3` is not between `Date1` and `Date2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have interchanged the dates in the if-condition.

Instead of checking, if 2022-02-06 is before 2022-02-07, you are currently checking 2022-02-07 is before 2022-02-06. Which is obviously wrong.

So you have to adjust your check.

For Example:

```
void main() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var lastYear = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -365));
  
  var dateToCheck = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -1));
  
  if( dateToCheck.isAfter(lastYear) && dateToCheck.isBefore(now))
  {
    print("dateToCheck is between now and lastYear");
  }
  else
  {
    print("dateToCheck is not between now and lastYear");
  }
}
```

or if you want to write `dateToCheck` within the function call, you could write it like this:

```
void main() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var lastYear = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -365));
  
  var dateToCheck = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -1));
  
  if( lastYear.isBefore(dateToCheck) && now.isAfter(dateToCheck) )
  {
    print("dateToCheck is between now and lastYear");
  }
  else
  {
    print("dateToCheck is not between now and lastYear");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you parse the dates as DateTime then fix the condition, it should work.
Side note: you should rename your variables to something more explicit, ex. dateMin/dateMax, dateLowerBound/dateUpperBound, etc.

```
void main() {
    final date1 = DateTime.parse('2022-02-07 20:06:14.379392');
    final date2 = DateTime.parse('2021-02-07 20:06:14.379393');
    final date3 = DateTime.parse('2022-02-06 00:00:00.000');

    if (date3.isBefore(date1) && date3.isAfter(date2)) {
        print("date3 is between date1 and date2"); // <- this is printed.
    }
    else {
        print("date3 isn't between date1 and date2");
    }
}
```